# Validation error in Backbone Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js

Ok I'm messing around with code to help me understand javascript better and Ive been playing with backbone. I may be missing it but my validation here isnt working right. I either get a "you must fill in both fields or it just submits even if a field is blank.

The function of addModel is to add a row to my parent view and save it all in one function which is causing me issues

```
Form = Backbone.View.extend({ //form view
    el: '.item-form',
    initialize: function(){
    }, 
    events: {
        'click #additem': 'addModel' // clicking on the add item button launches the addmodel function
    },
    addModel: function(){ // when the addmodel function fires it takes 
        var item = new Item({
            "itemName": this.$("#item").val(),//value of form input placed into  row template cell
            "price": this.$("#price").val()}); 

    // simple validation before adding to collection
        if(!_.isEmpty("#item") && !_.isEmpty("#price")){
            var items = new Items();
            items.add(item);
            $("#message").html("Please wait; the task is being added.");
            item.save(null, {success:
                //use the mongo id as the Item models id
                function (item, response,options) {
                    item.id= item.attributes._id.$id;
                    item.attributes.id = item.attributes._id.$id;
                    new ItemsView({collection: items});
                    $("#message").html("");
                }
            });
            this.$("#item").val('');//all this does is empty the field
            this.$("#price").val('');//all this does is empty the field
        } else {
           alert('Please fill in both fields');
        }
    }
});
```

heres the html for reference

```
<body>
<table class="itemTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tableBody">    
<script type="text/template" id="table-row">
<td><%= itemName %></td> <td><%= price %></td> <td> <button class="complete">Complete</button> <button class="remove">Remove</button></td> 
</script>

</tbody>
</table>

<form class="item-form">
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" placeholder="Item"/> <!-- goes to itemName in the template for the body -->
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Price" /><!--goes to price in the template for the body -->
<button type="button" id="additem">Add</button>
</form>
<div id="message"></div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation should compare the values of the inputs not simply the id's.

```
if(!_.isEmpty(this.$("#item").val()) && !_.isEmpty(this.$("#price").val())){
```